# Android Studio logcat keeps on running

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

Have tried the things like updating Google play servies, Wiping emulator data, using different API level for Emulators...

But keep on getting this error in Logcat:

> I/AudioController: internalShutdown
>   I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
>   I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
>   I/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled

Using Kotlin with Firebase to write an authentication.

What else can I check?

Comment: Pretty sure this is just the standard logcat output that happens regardless of what you're trying to do. `logcat` can filter based on app so you can restrict it to just the output you're looking for.